# Copy (only value and not formula) range of cells to another sheet in same file

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am using the following code. This code copies the cell formulas into the other sheet. Does anyone know how can I modify it to just copy the cell values and not formulas?

---

```
sub copyRangeOver()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 631

    Dim copyRange  As Range
    Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Coupling xyz data").Range("J" & 1 & ":V" & i)

    Dim countD As Integer
    countD = 1
    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Cells(countD, 1)

    Dim j As Integer
    j = 466
    Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Spring xyz data").Range("J" & 1 & ":V" & j)

    copyRange.Copy Destination:=Cells(i + 1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to specify this using `xlValues` or `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a direct value transfer which is faster than a Copy and Paste Special, Values and doesn't involve the clipboard.

```
Sub copyRangeOver()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, countD As Long
    Dim copyRange As Range

    i = 631
    countD = 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Coupling xyz data")
        Set copyRange = .Range("J" & 1 & ":V" & i)
        Cells(countD, 1).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count) = _
            copyRange.Value
    End With

    j = 466

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Spring xyz data")
        Set copyRange = .Range("J" & 1 & ":V" & j)
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count) = _
            copyRange.Value
    End With

End Sub
```

That duplicates your previous effort although it seems to me that there is some ambiguity in the destination(s) of the values. For a row to receive the values, you are using *i* in the second one and *CountD* in the first but there doesn't appear to be a relationship between them.

Comment: @Sushant - If *countD* is ever going to be larger than *1*, I believe the second destination should be `Cells(i + countD, 1).Resize(...` in order to skip ahead over the first value transfer.

Comment: Yes, better approach than copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

You need pastespecial:

```
copyRange.Copy
Cells(countD, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. It works fine but one problem. Earlier, after running the macro, the active cell would always be the last selection. Now with the modified code, (after running the macro) the content from 'Spring xyz data' sheet remains highlighted and the active cell is A632. How can I make A1 as active cell after running the updated macro?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally how it's done.

```
  copyRange.Copy
  Cells(i + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  application.cutcopymode=0
```